# Test to see if the IP is within a range

Tags: .htaccess, ip

I want to see if this IP `219.111.71.35` falls within the following IP ranges.

```
218.224.0.0/13
219.94.128.0/17
220.104.0.0/13
```

I just used [this](http://www.csgnetwork.com/ipinfocalc.html) site to see that the IP falls within the number 2 IP range in the list above. But I was wondering: is there an easier way like an IP range tester or something? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
11011010 . 11100000 . 00000000 . 00000000   218.224.0.0
00000000 . 00000111 . 11111111 . 11111111   /13 (netmask)
-----------------------------------------   bitwise OR
11011010 . 11100111 . 11111111 . 11111111   218.231.255.255

$your_ip = 219.111.73.35
if (($your_ip >= 218.224.0.0) && ($your_ip <= 218.231.255.255)) {
   ... falls within range ...
}
```

and similarly for any other ip range/mask.